# How to get typeof work inside class method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, typeof

For singleton, I often do it like this

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static id instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

But this `static id instance = nil` is not strict about type, so I want something like

```
static typeof(self) instance = nil
```

But `self` here is the Class singleton instance, which is readonly. How can I infer the typeof from this class method?

Comment: Why would you need it to be strict about type? Also, why using `id` instead of the class itself?

Comment: Are you trying to create a generic Singleton method that can infer the appropriate type automatically?  As @duci9y said, why not simply use the class name for the singleton class.  Surely it isn't that much work to change it for each singleton class you create

Comment: @Paulw11 actually, I'm creating a singleton macro. So it seems there no possible way